# Как дождаться генерации всех изображений?

Tags: javascript

Методом `Vue.js` генерирую изображения. Возникла проблема, которая заключается в том, что данная операция не синхронна и в массив `this.result` ничего не успевает записаться. Проблема должна решиться если обернуть в промис (метод вернёт `new Promis()`), но никак не получается это сделать.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      expand: false,
      svg: '',
      result: [],
      svgs: [
        '<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-30 -40 336.6666666666667 283.3333333333333" id="maker-svg" style="padding : 10px; display: none;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="13.333333333333334" stroke="#03a9f4" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)" style="stroke:#03a9f4;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)"><path d="M 23.333 223.333 L 73.333 23.333 L 173.333 23.333 L 223.333 223.333 L 23.333 223.333 Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><path d="M 173.333 23.333 L 173.333 13.333 L 223.333 13.333 L 223.333 223.333 L 223.333 233.333 L 23.333 233.333 L 23.333 223.333 L 23.333 13.333 L 73.333 13.333 L 73.333 23.333 L 13.333 23.333 L 13.333 223.333 L 23.333 223.333 L 23.333 13.333" id="gray" stroke="gray" style="stroke:gray" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><g id="captions"><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,123.333,246.667)" x="123.333" y="246.667">L: 200</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,198.333,0)" x="198.333" y="0">L1: 50</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,48.333,0)" x="48.333" y="0">L2: 50</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(270,0,123.333)" x="0" y="123.333">H: 200</text></g></g></svg>',
        '<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-72.35 -10 694.6166666666667 1495.6166666666666" id="maker-svg" style="padding : 10px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="83.13333333333333" stroke="#03a9f4" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)" style="stroke:#03a9f4;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)"><path d="M 145.483 1247 L 591.483 1247 L 591.483 0 L 145.483 0 L 145.483 1247 Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><path d="M 145.483 0 L 83.133 0 L 83.133 1247 L 145.483 1247 L 145.483 1309.35 L 591.483 1309.35 L 591.483 1247" id="gray" stroke="gray" style="stroke:gray" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><g id="captions"><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,368.483,1392.483)" x="368.483" y="1392.483">L: 446</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(270,0,623.5)" x="0" y="623.5">H: 1247</text></g></g></svg>',
        '<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-30 -40 336.6666666666667 283.3333333333333" id="maker-svg" style="padding : 10px; display: none;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="13.333333333333334" stroke="#03a9f4" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)" style="stroke:#03a9f4;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)"><path d="M 23.333 223.333 L 73.333 23.333 L 173.333 23.333 L 223.333 223.333 L 23.333 223.333 Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><path d="M 173.333 23.333 L 173.333 13.333 L 223.333 13.333 L 223.333 223.333 L 223.333 233.333 L 23.333 233.333 L 23.333 223.333 L 23.333 13.333 L 73.333 13.333 L 73.333 23.333 L 13.333 23.333 L 13.333 223.333 L 23.333 223.333 L 23.333 13.333" id="gray" stroke="gray" style="stroke:gray" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><g id="captions"><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,123.333,246.667)" x="123.333" y="246.667">L: 200</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,198.333,0)" x="198.333" y="0">L1: 50</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,48.333,0)" x="48.333" y="0">L2: 50</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(270,0,123.333)" x="0" y="123.333">H: 200</text></g></g></svg>',
      ],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    setShapeDraw() {
      this.svgs.forEach(pp => {

        const svg = pp;
        const div = document.createElement('div');

        div.innerHTML = svg;

        $(div).find('#captions text').css({
          'stroke': 'none',
          'fill': 'black',
        });

        $(div).find('#gray').css({
          'fill': 'none',
        });

        const source = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($(div).children()[0]);
        const blob = new Blob(['<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>' + source], {
          type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
        });
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const img = $($(document.createElement('div')).append('<img>').children()[0]).attr('width', 400).attr('height', 400)[0];

        img.onload = () => {
          const canvas = $(document.createElement('div')).append('<canvas></canvas>').children()[0];
          canvas.width = 400;
          canvas.height = 400;
          const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
          this.result.push(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        }

        img.src = url;
      });
      
      console.log(this.result);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-btn
          @click="setShapeDraw"
        >
          Generate PNG
        </v-btn>
        <div id="svg-container" v-html="svg">
          
        </div>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: и где тут асинхронная операция?

Comment: `в массив this.result ничего не успевает записаться.` - в момент вывода его в консоль. Потом, когда картинки  загрузились - он с данными

Comment: @Дмытрык Так вот в этом и проблема, сейчас я борюсь с этим, с помощью `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @ThisMan `img.onload` не?

Comment: объясните другими словами, какого результата Вы хотите достичь?

Comment: @Дмытрык Я хочу, чтобы только после создания всех изображений выполнилась следующая команда. Например тот же `console.log()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      expand: false,
      svg: '',
      result: [],
      svgs: [
        '<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-30 -40 336.6666666666667 283.3333333333333" id="maker-svg" style="padding : 10px; display: none;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="13.333333333333334" stroke="#03a9f4" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)" style="stroke:#03a9f4;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)"><path d="M 23.333 223.333 L 73.333 23.333 L 173.333 23.333 L 223.333 223.333 L 23.333 223.333 Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><path d="M 173.333 23.333 L 173.333 13.333 L 223.333 13.333 L 223.333 223.333 L 223.333 233.333 L 23.333 233.333 L 23.333 223.333 L 23.333 13.333 L 73.333 13.333 L 73.333 23.333 L 13.333 23.333 L 13.333 223.333 L 23.333 223.333 L 23.333 13.333" id="gray" stroke="gray" style="stroke:gray" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><g id="captions"><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,123.333,246.667)" x="123.333" y="246.667">L: 200</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,198.333,0)" x="198.333" y="0">L1: 50</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,48.333,0)" x="48.333" y="0">L2: 50</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(270,0,123.333)" x="0" y="123.333">H: 200</text></g></g></svg>',
        '<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-72.35 -10 694.6166666666667 1495.6166666666666" id="maker-svg" style="padding : 10px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="83.13333333333333" stroke="#03a9f4" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)" style="stroke:#03a9f4;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)"><path d="M 145.483 1247 L 591.483 1247 L 591.483 0 L 145.483 0 L 145.483 1247 Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><path d="M 145.483 0 L 83.133 0 L 83.133 1247 L 145.483 1247 L 145.483 1309.35 L 591.483 1309.35 L 591.483 1247" id="gray" stroke="gray" style="stroke:gray" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><g id="captions"><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,368.483,1392.483)" x="368.483" y="1392.483">L: 446</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(270,0,623.5)" x="0" y="623.5">H: 1247</text></g></g></svg>',
        '<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-30 -40 336.6666666666667 283.3333333333333" id="maker-svg" style="padding : 10px; display: none;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="13.333333333333334" stroke="#03a9f4" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)" style="stroke:#03a9f4;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)"><path d="M 23.333 223.333 L 73.333 23.333 L 173.333 23.333 L 223.333 223.333 L 23.333 223.333 Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><path d="M 173.333 23.333 L 173.333 13.333 L 223.333 13.333 L 223.333 223.333 L 223.333 233.333 L 23.333 233.333 L 23.333 223.333 L 23.333 13.333 L 73.333 13.333 L 73.333 23.333 L 13.333 23.333 L 13.333 223.333 L 23.333 223.333 L 23.333 13.333" id="gray" stroke="gray" style="stroke:gray" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><g id="captions"><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,123.333,246.667)" x="123.333" y="246.667">L: 200</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,198.333,0)" x="198.333" y="0">L1: 50</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,48.333,0)" x="48.333" y="0">L2: 50</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(270,0,123.333)" x="0" y="123.333">H: 200</text></g></g></svg>',
      ],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    setShapeDraw() {
/**/  const promises = this.svgs.map(pp => new Promise(resolve => {

        const svg = pp;
        const div = document.createElement('div');

        div.innerHTML = svg;

        $(div).find('#captions text').css({
          'stroke': 'none',
          'fill': 'black',
        });

        $(div).find('#gray').css({
          'fill': 'none',
        });

        const source = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($(div).children()[0]);
        const blob = new Blob(['<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>' + source], {
          type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
        });
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const img = $($(document.createElement('div')).append('<img>').children()[0]).attr('width', 400).attr('height', 400)[0];

        img.onload = () => {
          const canvas = $(document.createElement('div')).append('<canvas></canvas>').children()[0];
          canvas.width = 400;
          canvas.height = 400;
          const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          // console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
          this.result.push(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
/**/      resolve(); 
        }

        img.src = url;
/**/  }));
/**/  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
/**/    console.log('result', this.result);
/**/  });
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-btn
          @click="setShapeDraw"
        >
          Generate PNG
        </v-btn>
        <div id="svg-container" v-html="svg">
          
        </div>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </template>
</div>
```

Измененные строки я пометил `/**/`.